# Python, Numpy arrey error

Tags: python, numpy

error with numpy array on x
here's the code:

```
import numpy as np

111 x = np.array([[20, 20]
          [20, 20]] n13int43)
111 type(x)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
111 x.shape
(56, 43)
111 x.dtype
dtype('into.')
```

and the error:

```
  File "testme.py", line 3
    111 x = np.array([[20, 20]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please indent your code blocks with 4 spaces so that they format correctly (I just did it for you). See [editing help](stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: What is `111 x` supposed to mean? It appears as if you are mixing input and output from some kind of Python shell, creating a mish-mash which is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma at the end of the line: `x = np.array([[20, 20]`,  it should be like:

```
x = np.array([[20, 20],[20, 20]], int32)
```

where `int32` is the data type you want for the array.